# How to Dowload files in React-Native UWP application

Tags: react-native

I am new in reactnative mobile application development. I need to download file from webservice url in windows UWP. I checked with react-natived-fs and rn-fetch-blob its working only in android and ios. In windows UWP how can i achieve this download files.. Any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

i just write a bridge for this. now its working fine. For download i did

```
[ReactMethod]
        public async void download(string fileName, JObject _, IPromise promise)
        {          
            try
            {    
                StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                StorageFolder docFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
                string folderName = "DMSFolder";
                StorageFile file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample1.pdf",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                StorageFile docfile = await docFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample1.zip",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                var cli = new HttpClient();
                var uriBing = new Uri(@fileName);
                Byte[] bytes = await cli.GetByteArrayAsync(uriBing);
                IBuffer buffer = bytes.AsBuffer();
                await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(file, buffer);
                await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(docfile, buffer);

                if (file != null)
                {    
                    promise.Resolve(null);                        
                }
                else
                {
                    promise.Reject(null, "File Copied failed.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)//FieldAccessException
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occured====>" + e);
                promise.Reject(null, fileName, e);
            }               

        }
```